# OAuth Authentication Redirection Issue in .Net Muai Android

Tags: .net, xamarin

I'm facing an issue in my Xamarin.Android project when trying to implement redirection after OAuth authentication. The app uses a custom URL scheme (myapp://) for redirection back to the app after authentication.

Problem Description:
When attempting to authenticate with an OAuth provider (e.g., Google), authentication is successful, but redirection back to my app is not happening as expected

- I have a WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity class configured with the URL scheme uaifood in the AndroidManifest.xml file, as shown below:

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
              DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Microsoft.Maui.Authentication.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
    const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "myapp";
}
```

- On the server, after successful authentication, I am using the following code to redirect back to the app:

```
Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("myapp://");
```

Comment: 1. Is it a Xamarin Android or Maui Android project? 2. Is your project's Target Android version is set to **Android 11 (R API 30)** or higher?If so, please update your Android Manifest with queries that use Android's [package visibility requirements](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#get-started